# Stretch two buttons horizontally across all devices AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

I'm attempting to have two buttons side by side that look correct across all devices but no matter what constraints I seem to add in I keep getting issues similar to this (one button larger then the other):

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong as far as adding in constraints? I'm not using code for this simply doing it through the InterfaceBuilder in Storyboard.

Constraints set:

Reply: Leading Space, Bottom Space, Height Equals :45, Trailing to Delete Button

Delete: Trailing Space, Bottom Space, 32:9 Ratio, Height Equals :45, Leading to Reply Btn

Answer (score 13):

With both buttons selected, go to Editor > Pin > Widths Equally. Then set the height, leading/trailing space, space between the buttons, and bottom space.

Answer (score 3):

According to me add following constraints

- Select Reply button adds leading space and bottom space to superview
- Add center Y constraints to delete button
- Then align top and bottom space to delete button and also add trailing space to delete button
- After this select delete button add bottom space and trailing space.

I had similar operations on one of my view, please see this picture for more info[image: Reply Button]

Happy Codding :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constraint for equal widths, and also remove the '32:9 ratio' constraint, which is currently setting a width for the "Delete" button w/o having a set width for the "Reply" button. That's what's causing the issue.

If you then still have the leading & trailing edges pinned to their respective sides of the container view, and set the space between them to zero, then you should be good.